# Display a Drupal page without the page template

Tags: drupal, view, feed, drupal-themes

Hello I am trying to generate a Drupal node which would be similar to a feed page generated by views module. I need to generate an xml feed, so I would not want to show the regular drupal template that is showed up on every node. I am trying to understand how the views for feed works as I want to display my page in a similar fashion, without the drupal template. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Drupal you can theme any individual page to be completely different than the default template. So, if you have a node, let's say the url is "**node/14**", you can create a new template file called "**page-node-14.tpl.php**" in your theme folder. In this template you can add any html/xml markup you need. Also, for that specific node you should also create a "**node-14.tpl.php**" to theme that node's content.

If you want to display more nodes on a page, something like "**taxonomy/term/3**" (here you can find all nodes tagged with the term with the ID 3), you have to create a "**page-taxonomy-term-3.tpl.php**" template in your theme folder. To theme every node from one particular content type, you should create a "**node-news.tpl.php**" (this is for `news` node types) in your theme folder.

Please keep in mind that these template suggestions are for Drupal 6. In Drupal 7, the template name changed from "**node-news.tpl.php**" to "**node--news.tpl.php**"

Comment: so I would have to first create the node, and then create the node-number.tpl.php to make it specific to this page, isn't it?

Comment: take a look at these links: http://drupal.org/node/1089642 for Drupal 6 and http://drupal.org/node/1089656 for Drupal 7